# Why I can not attach the debugger to App Services running in this subscription?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-appservice

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I can attach the debugger to services running in my own subscription.
When I try to attach to services running in another sub from cloud explorer, I get various errors and the attachment never succeeds. The most common is:

> Unable to find a process called w3wp with arguments {app service name}. The process may still be starting, please try again.

When trying to attach under the Debug -> Attach to Process dialog, I get the following error:

> Unable to connect to {path}. The connection with remote endpoint was
> terminated.

I have owner role on the subscription, on the app service and on the app service plan.

Answer (score 0):

Please validate if you have enable debugging from azure platform side. Screen shot od the same from portal looks like:
[image]

Also please confirm if you have deploy application from VS.

Visual Studio remote debugging on azure app services used 4020, 4022, 4024 ports for debugging.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#app-service-ports